# Need to make NULL=Value evaluate to TRUE

Tags: sql-server, null, dimension

I have a dimension table I'm trying to create that would require records with NULLs to be overwritten by a value when all other non-null fields match.

This logic works and shows what I mean by "null=Value evaluates to TRUE":

```
UPDATE A
SET 
     A.SSN  =   COALESCE(A.SSN, B.SSN)      
    ,A.DOB  =   COALESCE(A.DOB, B.DOB)          
    ,A.ID_1 =   COALESCE(A.ID_1, B.ID_1)                
    ,A.ID_2 =   COALESCE(A.ID_2, B.ID_2)
    ,A.ID_3 =   COALESCE(A.ID_3, B.ID_3)
    ,A.ID_4 =   COALESCE(A.ID_4, B.ID_4)
FROM #TESTED1 A
    INNER JOIN #TESTED1 B
        ON  (A.SSN = B.SSN
            OR A.SSN IS NULL 
            OR B.SSN IS NULL)
        AND (A.DOB = B.DOB
            OR A.DOB IS NULL 
            OR B.DOB IS NULL)
        AND (A.ID_1 = B.ID_1
            OR A.ID_1 IS NULL 
            OR B.ID_1 IS NULL)
        AND (A.ID_2 = B.ID_2
            OR A.ID_2 IS NULL 
            OR B.ID_2 IS NULL)
        AND (A.ID_3 = B.ID_3    
            OR A.ID_3 IS NULL 
            OR B.ID_3 IS NULL)
        AND (A.ID_4 = B.ID_4    
            OR A.ID_4 IS NULL 
            OR B.ID_4 IS NULL)
WHERE A.ArbitraryTableID <> B.ArbitraryTableID
```

but takes exponentially longer the more records that are evaluated, 10k records takes 9sec, 100k records takes 9min, etc. I'm trying to do an initial load of around 30mil records and then I will have to evaluate the entire table in a MERGE operation with another 10k records every day.

For example I would need the following three rows (that all exist on the same table) to combine into two rows with all values populated:
[image: Three record Example]

Just like this:
[image: Three Row Example Solved]

Unfortunately members can have  multiple IDs so I can't count on any one of these IDs to be unique or even exist at all to cut down on my join conditions.

Comment: `NULL` doesn't equal anything. If you need to compare to `NULL` you have to use `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NILL`. The behaviour is by design and desired, as `NULL` is an unknown value.

Comment: Could you clarify the last sentence of your question?  Do you mean a single member (1 ssn) could have multiple rows with different values for `ID_1` etc.?

Comment: Yes. A single "member" could have changed their ID_n and so will have 2 rows with different ID_n and all other entries duplicated by design.

Comment: I understand how ANSI nulls work but unless you have a different way to join a range of fields with NULLs in them I need (to write my above JOIN logic in a different way) ISNULL(a.ID_n, TRUE) = ISNULL(b.ID_n, TRUE).

Comment: Is that supposed to be two different tables? I.e., should the query read `INNER JOIN #TESTED2 B`?

Comment: No. It is supposed to be a self join. It makes more sense when you see it in an UPDATE statement but I didn't think I needed it for this question. I'll add it in so you can see exactly what I'm looking for in the final results.

Comment: `NULL` is considered less than any non-`NULL` value, so `MAX` can be of use here, with an appropriate `GROUP BY`. For testing equality, the property that `MIN(x) = MAX(x)` is equivalent to all values of the set being equal can be used.

Comment: If I'm understanding your suggestion correctly you're trying to use `MIN()` or `MAX()` in the `UPDATE`? To utilize `GROUP BY` I would have either write out 5! (120) `GROUP BY` queries, or a dynamic SQL variation of that. Any ID can be `NULL` and any record can join on 1 or more IDs as long as none of them have a different value. I don't see how

Comment: Yes my bad, I was assuming you have an actual business key for your rows that you can merge the rest of the columns on (`ID` in the above) and the problem was just filling in the blanks with at most one new unique value. If you don't have that, things get, well, exciting. To the point where I'd start considering doing this outside SQL entirely, as set-based logic pretty much starts to fail here. If you must keep it in the DB, a CLR aggregate that dynamically builds a dictionary (with a custom `IComparable`) could do it -- that assumes you know your way around .NET, though.

Comment: Are you updating the whole table even when there is no null column is a row? Does the process take place into temp table? How about the statistics of the table?

Comment: 1. Yes, using this method updates every record on the table.   


2. No, I'm using a generic table structure to highlight the problem I'm trying to solve as the actual table is not something I can post on SO.  



3. Using the current (slow) method I described in the initial post is not an acceptable level of performance so this table doesn't have any statistics as of yet.

Comment: I'm bothered by the statement "I can't count on any one of these IDs to be unique". why are they called IDs then? your WHERE clause seems to assume they are unique, but NULLable.

Comment: These IDs are being aggregated from 3 source tables. These source tables come from different parts of the business and there is a lot of overlap but I can't count on a Customer being present in all 3 systems. Since I can't count any of the IDs being unique or `NOT NULL` it means I have to do this crazy join. This table also has an historical aspect, so when a customer changes their ID in one system, the IDs from the other systems have to be duplicated on a new row because they are also that person. 

I understand it's not ideal but being able to translate an ID across systems is vital.

Answer (score 0):

For performance of this query, make sure you have an index sorting all the criteria you are making your join on.

I did a quick example of what you described:

`declare @test table (
    row_name NVARCHAR(50),
    id1 int null,
    id2 int null,
    id3 int null
)

insert into @test values('row1', 1,2,3), ('row2',1,4,5), ('row3',11,null,null), ('row4',null,4,null), ('row5',3,6,5), ('row6',3,null,null)

select * 
from @test t1 
inner join @test t2 on (
    (t1.id1 = t2.id1 
    or t1.id1 is null
    or t2.id1 is null)
     and (
     t1.id2 = t2.id2
     or t1.id2 is null
     or t2.id2 is null)
     and (
     t1.id3 = t2.id3
     or t1.id3 is null
     or t2.id3 is null)
 )
 where t1.row_name <> t2.row_name
 order by t1.row_name`

There are a couple of possible problems I see in my test output:

1. row3 and row4 in my example match because they have none of the same IDs. I'm guessing this is not desired but if you really have several independent systems with different keys, is it possible that you have a lot of rows that fall into this scenario? Every row with id1 set and no other keys and every row with id2 set and no other keys will match.
2. row1 and row4 do not match even though they should through transitivity (row1.id1 -> row2.id1, row2.id2-> row4.id2)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your response to my comment, I suggest the following solution:

- a master record identifying the member/customer
- child records for each master record storing the respective IDs

Replace your `UPDATE` statement with

- `INSERT`s into the master table for all records in table `A` that are guaranteed to be unique (e.g. SSN).
- `INSERT`s into the child table for all records in table `A` with not-NULL ID attributes
- mark records in table `A` as processed by `UPDATE`ing a foreign key column referencing the master records `IDENTITY` primary key
- `INSERT` into the child table all records from `A` that you can safely assign to existing master records, and again set the FK

This solution would resolve the performance issues resulting from a 5-way `JOIN`, and also mark processed source records as processed.